# Zero-fill numbers to 2 digits with sed

Tags: linux, sed, openwrt

Input:

```
201103 1 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHING
201102 7 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETH ING
201103 11 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SO METHING
201104 3 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMET HING
201106 1 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHI NG
```

Desired output:

```
201103 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHING
201102 07 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETH ING
201103 11 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SO METHING
201104 03 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMET HING
201106 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHI NG
```

How can I add a `0` if there is only a single digit, e.g. `1` in the "day" part? I need this date format: YYYYMM DD.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/' ./infile
201103 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHING
201102 07 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETH ING
201103 11 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SO METHING
201104 03 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMET HING
201106 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHI NG
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? This is the first time I'm looking at the `\<[0-9]\>` construct which I think is the one responsible for matching the single digits but not sure what this construct is called. Thanks.

Comment: \< means: start of a 'word' ... [0-9] means a single digit from 0 to 9 ... \> means: end of a 'word' ... word: a token which is whitespace delimited (or begins/ends at start/end of the line, for \< and \> respectively)... PS. I just tried punctuation marks.. they are also delimiters.

Comment: You can also do this without capturing parentheses: `&` in the replacement string will use the matched LHS -- `sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/'`

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware that `<>` is a word boundary in shell regex syntax. Come to think of it, even `sed 's/\b[0-9]\b/0&/' also works. Thank you both. :)

Comment: @sasuke: `<>` is a feature of *extended regex* (not of the shell, as such)... depending on which version and which options you use, `sed` and the `shell` can both use either  *extended* or *standard* regex ... standard regex uses `\<\>`

Comment: @fred.bear thanks for taking the reigns on the explanations

Comment: @glenn good call on `&`. I'm all for saving keystrokes

Answer (score 18):

Another solution: `awk '{$2 = sprintf("%02d", $2); print}'`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (non-sed) way to use *bash* with *extended regex*..
This method, allows scope to do more complex processing of individual lines. (ie. more than just regex substitutions)

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^(.+\ )([0-9]\ .+)$ ]]  
    then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}0${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" 
    else echo "$line"
    fi
done <<EOF
201103 1 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHING
201102 7 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETH ING
201103 11 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SO METHING
201104 3 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMET HING
201106 1 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHI NG
EOF
```

output:

```
201103 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHING
201102 07 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETH ING
201103 11 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SO METHING
201104 03 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMET HING
201106 01 /mnt/hdd/PUB/SOMETHI NG
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]) / 0\1 /' ./input
```

This grabs lonely numbers, strips them of whitespace with a group `' ([0-9]) '`, then places them back in with 0 and whitespace padding `' 0\1 '`.

The `-E` option allows for modern RegEx expressions on OSX (so you don't have to use `"\"` so often), `-r` does the same thing on the linux systems I've tested.

Answer (score -1):

```
while read a b c
do 
new_format=$(printf "%02d" $b)
echo "$a $new_format $c"
done </tmp/input
```